# Protected sheet creating hidden hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

When I protect a sheet and attempt to edit a cell that has for example an Index it will teleport me to that sheet and highlight the column the index is attempting to return. This is not that nice, as sometimes I am referencing other closed workbooks. How can I disable this feature and is there a way to have it go directly to the result of the index instead of highlighting the entire column?

To reproduce problem,

Create Index Formula, Protect Sheet, Double Click that cell, it pops up you can't edit it and then teleports you to the cells that are contained in the array portion of the index. You can imagine how this can become a problem when you are protecting cells to prevent users from editing things they shouldn't and instead it brings them strait to another place they shouldn't be!

I have tried:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

but it still pops up the error that the sheet is protected and teleports me. `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)` doesn't seem to be capturing this event either.

Comment: Interesting question. But I posted an answer which solves this at my end. Test it at yours. You don't even need VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid such, select all the cells you want protected and then on *Format Cells* go to *Protection Tab*.

[image]

Check the **Hidden** check box. 
Then protect the worksheet and try double clicking the cell again. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
Index(array,,)
```

Whatever cell references are in that array field even if you place them in an if will be opened up by Excel when the sheet is protected. A VBA solution to this problem is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Locked Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This solution works because it only creates the secret hyperlink(which is not captured by the hyperlink event) when you double click.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the cell locked, the best solution I found is to put the hyperlink in a text box.